# How to typeset absolute values and norms in ConTeXt

Tags: context

How to properly absolute values and norms in ConTeXt?
I currently use:

```
\m{|x|\leq|y|}
```

But the height does not adapt to the content (same thing for `\mid`).

Comment: I don't know Context, but take a look at the `mathtools` package and its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command (§ 3.6, Paired Delimiters, pp. 25-30 of the documentation).

Comment: @Bernard I don't think you can use latex packages in context

Comment: @daleif: I thought some were compatible. Am I entirely wrong?

Comment: Actually, it depends on the command used by the dev. If only plain tex is used there is no compatibility issue (this is almost the case for `tikz`) but AFAIK `mathtools` is not compatible.

Comment: @Bernard not sure, never used context, there are some low level packages that also support context (like tikz). Not sure about amsmath

Comment: You can use the `mathfence` mechanism, e.g. `\m{\fenced[bar]{x} \le \fenced[bar]{y}}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `\fenced` command.  For example:

```
\starttext

\startformula
  \fenced[doublebar]{\int \psi(r) dr} = 1
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

[image]

You can find a list of defined fences in [`math-fen.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/70a938c4934f042face9805fc4c392c0676b11d5/tex/context/base/mkiv/math-fen.mkiv#L269-L307).

If you don't want to use the `\fenced` macro, you can also use the fences directly with `\L` and `\R` prefix.  These will also scale automatically and have to matched, just like `\left` and `\right`.

```
\starttext

\startformula
  \Ldoublebar \int \psi(r) dr \Rdoublebar = 1
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

The output is the same.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the existing answers, I would suggest to add these as new commands, with

```
\definemathfence[abs][left="007C,right="007C,command=yes]
\definemathfence[norm][left="2016,right="2016,command=yes]
```

Complete example below:

```
\definemathfence[abs][left="007C,right="007C,command=yes]
\definemathfence[norm][left="2016,right="2016,command=yes]
\starttext
\startTEXpage[offset=4mm]
Now we can type
\startformula
\abs{x}\geq\abs{\frac{y}{z}},\quad \norm{x}\geq\norm{\frac{y}{z}}
\stopformula
And if you think the sizes get wrong, you can adjust them like this:
\startformula
\abs{x}\geq\abs[size=2]{\frac{y}{z}},\quad \norm{x}\geq\norm[size=2]{\frac{y}{z}}
\stopformula
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

[image: This is a picture showing the output of the code above]

Comment: You don’t have to set the `left` and `right` values when you inherit the symbols from `bar` and `doublebar` with `\definemathfence [abs] [bar] [command=yes]` and `\definemathfence [norm] [doublebar] [command=yes]`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on this @WolfgangSchuster, I did not know! (At the point where I needed them for myself I just copied them from the source). I can add as a comment that I have asked for support for the possibility to write `\abs[size=Big]{\frac{y}{z}}` (syntax choice inspired from mathtools) to have `\Bigl|` and `\Bigr`. I hope it will be added after the TeXLive freeze.

Answer (score 1):

`\left|` and `\right|` scale automatically:

```
\m{\left| x \right| \leq \left| y^2 \right|}
```

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that unlike in LaTeX, `\|` is only a single vertical bar.  To get the double vertical bar use `\Vert`.